# Why am I able to access flask app on docker without port mapping

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

I was under the impression that you could only access a program in a docker container exposed on a port through a port on the host by mapping the port with the -p flag.

e.g:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 myimage
```

However, when I run a docker container with a simple flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route("/")
def hello():
   return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   server.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

copy src/ .

CMD ["python","./server.py"]
```

It shows as running on 172.17.0.2:5000 and I am able to access it there on the host. Am I misunderstanding? If a program in docker runs on a port will it automatically grab a 172.0.0.x ip and expose it's default port on that IP to the host if the port is not explicitly mapped?

Answer (score 0):

The default docker bridge network is 172.17.0.0/16 of which the host is a part of. So going to 172.17.0.2:5000 routes the traffic into the docker bridge network.

By mapping the port like this:

```
docker run -p 80:5000 myimage
```

The Flask App is then accessible from 172.17.0.2:5000 or 127.0.0.1 or on your network from another machine by going to the host machines IP.